# Apache Zeppelin with Athena handling session token using jdbc Interpreter

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-s3, apache-zeppelin, amazon-athena

I am trying to connect Athena with **Apache Zeppelin**.I need to handle secret_key, Access_key, and Session_token. I am feeling hard to establish my connection with the Zeppelin JDBC interpreter.
I am following the steps as mentioned in [this block](https://medium.com/@yutaimai/using-amazon-athena-with-apache-zeppelin-464a85678c46),

If any one can help me out in establishing the connection with AWS Session token approach that would be helpful.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The main docs for this are here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html

I found there are 2 driver versions, -1.1.0 and -1.0.1 . I could only get Zeppelin working with 1.1.0, and the links on that page don't go to that file, the only way to get it was using the aws s3 cp command
e.g.

```
aws s3 cp s3://athena-downloads/drivers/AthenaJDBC41-1.1.0.jar .
```

although I've given feedback on that page so it should be fixed soon.

Regarding the parameters, you use `default.user` and enter the Access_Key, `default.password` and enter the Secret_key. The `default.driver` should be com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver
The default.s3_staging_dir is actually the bucket where csv results are written so needs to match your athena settings.

There is no mention of where you might put a session token, however, you could always try putting it on the jdbc connection string ( which goes in `default.url` parameter value)

e.g.

```
jdbc:awsathena://athena.{REGION}.amazonaws.com:443?SessionToken=blahblahsomethingrealsessiontokengoeshere
```

but of course, replace {REGION} with the actual aws region and use your real session token.